# How to do selections on two tables and then join them in mySQL

Tags: mysql, r, database, dplyr

I have two tables, A and B. Table A has two columns, "ID", and "age". Table B has two columns, "ID", and "grade". I want to select rows in A whose age >25, rows in B whose grade<90, then join the results together.

In R, this can be achieved by the code:

```
library(dplyr)
A = data.frame("ID"=1:10,
               "age"=21:30)

B = data.frame("ID"=1:20,
               "Grade"=81:100)

sub_A = filter(A, age > 25)
sub_B = filter(B,Grade<90)

result = inner_join(sub_A,sub_B,by="ID")
```

How to do the same thing in mySQL? More specifically, is there a way in mySQL to store query results into new variables such as sub_A and sub_B, then join the sub_A and sub_B together?

I tried using "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE" but I do not have the permission to create a temporary table in the database.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to join two subqueries:

```sql
select *
from (
    select *
    from table_a 
    where age > 25
) sub_a
inner join (
    select *
    from table_b
    where grade < 90
) sub_b using(ID)
```

But there is no need for that. You can just join the two tables (on `ID`) and filter the data in the same WHERE clause:

```sql
select *
from table_a a
join table_b b using(ID)
where a.age   > 25
  and b.grade < 90
```

Comment: Still another variant is moving the `WHERE` expressions to the `ON` clause to filter during the join instead of after. But since the `WHERE` is the implicit join may have same execution plan with `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: @Parfait The engine can do that optimization without our help. It will examine any condition as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The OP has used `dplyr` to demonstrate the expected result he wants to achieve using `mySQL`.

For the sake of completeness and because the syntax of `data.table` is  [similar to `SQL`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html#enhanced-1b), I would like to show how the OP's requirement can be implemented using `data.table` in two ways:

```
library(data.table)

# filter/select before merge
merge(setDT(A)[age > 25], setDT(B)[Grade < 90])

# filter/select after  merge
merge(setDT(A), setDT(B))[age > 25 & Grade < 90]
```

Both statements return the same result:

> ```
>    ID age Grade
> 1:  6  26    86
> 2:  7  27    87
> 3:  8  28    88
> 4:  9  29    89
> ```